# How to find a dynamically created <style> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a `<style>` element with javascript like this:

```
function createMyStyle(selector , rule) {
   j$("head").append('<style type="text/css">' + selector + '{' + rule + '}' + '</style>');
}
```

I don't want to create this element every time, but to find out
if this `<style>` element was inserted already, and then use something like this to add my rules to it:

```
if( stylesheet.addRule ) {
    stylesheet.addRule(selector, rule);
} 
else if( stylesheet.insertRule ) {
    stylesheet.insertRule(selector + ' { ' + rule + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
}
```

I create this `<style>` in one piece and not with pure DOM because IE can't do innerHTML to document.createElement('style').

I tried giving the `<style>` an `id` and do something like ...

```
for( var i in document.styleSheets ) {
    if( !document.styleSheets[i].id) {
```

but this can't be done because theres no `id` attribute to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this with jQuery:

```
if($("style").length > 0){
  // this means you have a style  element in your document
}
```

Comment: I have dozens of <style> elements in the page, I cant which is the one i previously created.

Answer (score 0):

Giving it an id *should* work.

```
$('head').append('<style id="some-id"> ... </style>');

console.log($('#some-id'));
```

However, in case you're not aware, [there are much easier ways](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS) to add and remove styles from a document in jQuery.

Comment: The link you gave me if for styling each individual element. its not really what I need. image the element doesn't even exist yet. even if it is, its really a lot slower and less safe to put style attribute on each element rather that declare a <style> for them all.

Comment: I see what you mean; feel free to disregard that part of my answer.  The solution to your problem is still to make sure your style element is getting assigned an id, make sure it's properly getting added to the DOM, and then accessing it by id.